# Why does the payload invalid error appears?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gT8C3.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gT8C3.png)I'm getting a payload invalid error for every artisan command:

![][2]

My application was working fine previously without any error, until I ran the app a few days ago on localhost and this error is shown.

Comment: Which laravel version you are using?

Comment: Also, check this first: https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/LogManager/issues/28

Comment: Heyy, thank you  for reverting, i am actually using a web application cloned from github it was working properly after doing everything written on the readme file then i made some changes in the blade files,this changes were seen in the application and worked properly then i turned off my pc after 2 days when i tried to open my app this error was coming,please help i am new to laravel

Comment: Try to run `composer update`

Comment: i tried composer install but it was of no use after downloading and updating some files it showed "Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
The batch file cannot be found."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The payload invalid issue arises when the blades are of different version and the vendor files are of different version.A simple solution is to copy all the content in your current page and then copy it inside a newly created blade with the same version as of the vendor files.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an old version of the views. Please, run the following commands and try again:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

```
php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: any code with an artisan in it wont execute and this "In Encrypter.php line 195:

  The payload is invalid." error is shown

Comment: I need more info. Can you show me what will show up if you run any url in the browser?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gT8C3.png this is the screenshot of the error appearing on the web browser.@MEDZ

Comment: Check those threads. I believe they cover your issue:
1) https://laravel.io/forum/04-03-2014-decryptexception
2) https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/daeling-with-decryptexceptioninvalid-data